# Show long text in short TextView?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, text, textview

How to create a TextView with a long text so that the text in this TextView is automatically reviewed and displayed from end to end like horizontal slides?

In fact, I want textview to scroll automatically and scroll again from the beginning after the text is finished.

The image is the output of my code, but I do not want this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aE7F4.png)

Comment: I didnt understand what you mean by horizontal lines. Do you want to extra characters to be dots at the end? Like `Elephant` will be `Elep...` if it exceeds the textview limit

Comment: No
I do not want ... to be.
In fact, I want textview to scroll automatically and scroll again from the beginning after the text is finished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer!
You must add these features to TextView :

```
android:ellipsize = "marquee"
android:fadingEdge = "horizontal"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit = "marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally = "true"
android:singleLine = "true"
```

then:

TextView txt = findViewById(R.id.text);
txt.setSelected(true);

Comment: Well I always use those two lines only if I need a scrollng text. But if this works for you go ahead.

Answer (score 2):

make `ellipsize=marquee` and `singleLine=true` within `textView`

Comment: I do not know if I wanted to or not.
I showed a picture of the output if I edited the question, but I do not want to ... OK and replace the text so that the text scrolls automatically and the text is displayed.
I did what you said but it did not work and no change was observed.